# JCalendar Java Eclipse

Tags: java, jcalendar

Tengo una duda como ago para recuperar una fecha que se a guardado en un jtable en formato `"yyyy/mm/dd"` 
este es mi codigo pero no compila me sale

> Unparseable date: "2019-11-10"

```
String fecha = table_1.getValueAt(1, 8).toString();
                SimpleDateFormat formatoDelTexto = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
                Date fechaN = null;

                    try {
                        fechaN = (Date) formatoDelTexto.parse(fecha);
                        date_nacimiento.setDate(fechaN);

                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage());
                    }
```

No entiendió por que se origina este error :c

Comment: `mm` hace referencia a los minutos. `MM` hace referencia a los meses. Prueba con esto: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: Y te recomienod leer el artículo acerca de un [mcve]

Comment: Por si alguien ocupa ayuda con esto: no se puede parsear una fecha con guinoes si ya especificamos que en nuestro formato lleva diagonales. Saludos.